# scala infix function with additional parameters

Tags: scala

Is there a way to create a function that can be passed additional parameters in infix notation in scala?

Something like this: `a op(additionalParam) b`

Edit: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Maybe someone can convince me otherwise? In the end I just need to pass a number to `op`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [language specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#prefix-infix-and-postfix-operations) has this:

```
InfixExpr       ::=  PrefixExpr
                  |  InfixExpr id [nl] InfixExpr
PrefixExpr      ::=  [‘-’ | ‘+’ | ‘!’ | ‘~’] SimpleExpr
```

So infix only works with a simple `id` between two expressions. The `id` is the name of a method on the object returned by the first expression that takes an argument compatible with the type of the second expression.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm now trying to do is create a function that takes the parameter and returns a function that I can then use with infix notation

Comment: Not quite: OP’s syntax isn’t valid (but that’s why OP is asking at all), but OP’s _idea_ is absolutely supported as `a op (b, additionalParam)`. In the same spec link, see a few paragraphs later: “The right-hand operand of a left-associative operator may consist of several arguments enclosed in parentheses, e.g. ; ; (₁, …, ₙ). This expression is then interpreted as .(₁, …, ₙ).” The syntax definition (quoted in this answer) makes no special mention of it because _grammatically,_ this is just the standard tuple syntax inside the right-hand-side `InfixExpr`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but you might do something like this.

```
class A {
  def op(b: B): C = new C
  def op(otherParam: OP): A = new A
}

import scala.language.postfixOps

a op b //->C
a op addedParam op b //->C
```

Just replace the `A`, `B`, `C`, and `OP` types with something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you [can pass multiple arguments to infix operators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) (in both Scala 2 and Scala 3), but the exact syntax is different from your example: you write all the parameters in parentheses on the right-hand side of the operator, in the same order as they are declared:

```scala
class A {
  def op(b: B, additionalParam: AP) = ???
}

a op (b, additionalParam)
```

In fact, if `op` is overloaded, this takes precedence over a single tuple parameter:

```scala
class A {
  def op(b: B, additionalParam: AP) = "two arguments"
  def op(b: (B, AP)) = "one argument"
}

a op (b, additionalParam)    // two arguments
a op ((b, additionalParam))  // one argument
```